# Randomly replace 20% of dataframe column with random of 2-10 NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas

I have used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149738/pandas-replace-values-with-nan-at-random) to replace values with NaN randomly.

I'm looking for the same idea but also random numbers of NaNs between 2-10, as the following:

[image: where in the first replacement it added 3 NaNs, the second replacement added one NaN.]

Comment: what do mean with `NaNs between 2-10` , a slice of column `A`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I meant for the random replacement, also random NANs, for column B as what happened for the third row, it could be n numbers between 2-10 of NaNs.

Comment: So it's actually not 20%, just 2-10 NaNs

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 11),
                   'B': np.random.random(10)})

# columns other than A
cols = df.columns.difference(['A'])

# assign 2-10 NaNs
import random
df[cols] = df[cols].sample(n=len(df)-random.randint(2, 10))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A         B
0   1       NaN
1   2       NaN
2   3  0.742521
3   4       NaN
4   5  0.648175
5   6  0.574785
6   7  0.958592
7   8  0.704552
8   9       NaN
9  10  0.296980
```

Comment: I also need random numbers of NaNs between 2-10

Comment: See update, I simplified the logic